# retrieve data in xml, where the data is in xml

Tags: javascript, xml

I have the following xml, in my server as

```
<root>
<name> arun</name>
<score> 20 </score>
<name> varun</name>
<score> 120 </score>
</root>
```

Can i get the maximum of the score by writing some javascripts in xml and retrieve the details as html

Comment: are you trying to retrieve the high score and inject it into an HTML page?  If so, this is possible, but we need to know what you have tried first.

Comment: And why name and score are not in surrounding tag? Now it doesnt looks like a tree.

Comment: Brian, you are right. I am new to xml, so i dint know where is the starting point and how to try or anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some semi code you could try, it could be made better but it's a good starting point. Please use Firefox with firebug plugin or Chrome to test it, press F12 to open the development tools and check out the console for errors

```
var httpRequest;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE 8 and older
    httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if (httpRequest.readyState === 4 && httpRequest.status === 200) {
    // everything is good, the response is received
    // the responseXML should be your xml file as a JS document object
    console.log(this.responseXML);
    // get all the score elements
    var scores = this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("score");
    var arr=[]; //array containing score values
    var tmpNum; // temporary store score value in here
    for(var i=0;i<scores.length;i++){
      //try to convert the score element innerHTML to an integer
      tmpNum=parseInt(scores[i].innerHTML.trim(),10);
      // if tmpNum is a number then store it in the scores array
      if(!isNaN(tmpNum)){
        arr.push(tmpNum);
      }
    }
    //sort the arr (lowest first)
    arr.sort();
    // get last element (is highest)
    console.log("Highest score:",arr[arr.length-1]);

  } else {
    // still not ready
  }
};
httpRequest.open('GET', "your URL");
httpRequest.send();
```